# SRC changes from Package to folders for all projects

Tags: eclipse

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sE4siTbywF8/Uny2CAzkwYI/AAAAAAAAAPc/tM7sQ_rtpN8/s1600/123123.PNG
https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-WV76Fqqag94/Uny2CJyk8TI/AAAAAAAAAPY/geInY3DIaGs/s1600/1231234.png

I don't know if I have touch any settings on eclipse but previously the src folders are suppose to be package and when I right click the options are different previously I even have a build path option anyone could tell me how to change back to my previous setting?

Tried restarted eclipse and it's useless

---

Solved by resetting perspective Windows>Reset perspective

Comment: Your screenshots probably don't tell the whole story: can you tell us which view you are in? (could it be the navigator view?)

Comment: Ahhh nvm i solved it Windows > Reset perspective

Comment: Please, don't add "solved". This is done marking an answer as correct, write your own if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a shot in the dark (see my comment) but try: the menu Windows --> Show view --> Package Explorer.